# UrlDownloadToFile to Memory

Tags: c++, wininet

I'm using `URLDownloadToFile()` to download images from a web server to a directory on my desktop.  If, instead of saving the images to disk, I wanted to read them into memory (like a byte array or base64 string or something), is there a function similar to `URLDownloadToFile()` that can achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

There is [`URLOpenStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775129(v=vs.85).aspx), [`URLOpenBlockingStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`URLOpenPullStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775128(v=vs.85).aspx) which allow you to download into memory.

From these three, [`URLOpenBlockingStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to be the most straightforward to use as it returns an `IStream` pointer from which you can synchronously read in a loop. Although it's not a single *do-all* function like `URLDownloadToFile()` it's not much difficult to use.

Here is a complete example console application for [`URLOpenBlockingStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127(v=vs.85).aspx). It downloads from an URL and writes the response to stdout. Instead of this, you could store the response in a `std::vector` or do whatever you like with it.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Urlmon.h>   // URLOpenBlockingStreamW()
#include <atlbase.h>  // CComPtr
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment( lib, "Urlmon.lib" )

struct ComInit
{
    HRESULT hr;
    ComInit() : hr( ::CoInitialize( nullptr ) ) {}
    ~ComInit() { if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) ::CoUninitialize(); } 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ComInit init;

    // use CComPtr so you don't have to manually call Release()
    CComPtr<IStream> pStream;  

    // Open the HTTP request.
    HRESULT hr = URLOpenBlockingStreamW( nullptr, L"http://httpbin.org/headers", &pStream, 0, nullptr );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Could not connect. HRESULT: 0x" << std::hex << hr << std::dec << "\n"; 
        return 1;
    }

    // Download the response and write it to stdout.
    char buffer[ 4096 ];
    do
    {
        DWORD bytesRead = 0;
        hr = pStream->Read( buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead );

        if( bytesRead > 0 )
        {
            std::cout.write( buffer, bytesRead );
        }
    } 
    while( SUCCEEDED( hr ) && hr != S_FALSE );

    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Download failed. HRESULT: 0x" << std::hex << hr << std::dec << "\n";
        return 2;
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no *single* do-all function in the Win32 API to download a URL resource into memory, like `URLDownloadToFile()`  does for a file.  You will have to write your own function that requests the URL and then reads the data into memory.

For example, using [`InternetOpenUrl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098.aspx) or  [`HttpOpenRequest()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233.aspx)/[`HttpSendRequest()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384247.aspx), and then [`InternetReadFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103.aspx).  See [Downloading Resources from the WWW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384322.aspx#Downloading_resource) on MSDN for more details.

Or using any other HTTP/S library/API of your choosing.

Comment: Wrong, see my answer.

Comment: @zett42: that is not exactly "a function similar to `URLDownloadToFile()`", though.  You have to first open a stream, and then read from the stream.  Those are separate operations, and so not unlike my answer, just using a different API.  Notice that I said "*There is no **single do-all** function like `URLDownloadToFile()` ...*", which is true.

Comment: The do-all function would be `URLOpenStream()`, I've just choosen `URLOpenBlockingStream()` as the simpler example.

Comment: @zett42: `URLOpenStream()` is hardly a *do-all* function, as it requires the caller to pass in a separate `IBindStatusCallback` object to handle the `OnDataAvailable` callback, and the data is provided in `STDMEDIUM` format, which requires extra function calls to extract the data, since it could be in `HGLOBAL`, `IStream`, or `IStorage` format.  A do-all function would be one where the caller simply passes in a URL and a memory block or output stream, and the function populates the output completely without any work from the caller. There is no single Win32 API function that does that.

Comment: Fair enough, I get it.